# Why is the word `false` written blue and the word `FALSE` written purple in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ide, syntax-highlighting

Why does Visual Studio change the word color depending on the way it is entered:

`false` with blue, but `FALSE` with purple.
`true` with blue but `TRUE` with purple.

Is there any difference in the meaning of them and if yes what is it?

Comment: `FALSE` and `TRUE` are macros.

Comment: That is called [syntax highlighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_highlighting), and is performed by the text editor, not by the compiler. What color(s) the text editor uses has absolutely no bearing on how the compiler parses your code or how your program runs.

Comment: @Insilico: It's not _absolutely_ unrelated. We're talking about Visual Studio here; it definitely compiles the text as you type (IntelliSense). That's how it produces the red squiggles on errors.

Comment: @MSalters: True, although I'm talking "the Visual C++ compiler that produces the binary" and not "the EDG front-end that the IDE uses for Intellisense".

Comment: Download a program from somewhere (may I suggest something off [MSDN Code Gallery](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Direct3D-Tutorial-Win32-829979ef), build the project and then open a .cpp file in Visual Studio. Note all the syntax coloring. Then open the same .cpp in Notepad. If you know what the color mean it's an extremely useful tool, but it can be distracting too...

Comment: Query : Is this que really belongs to SO ? or it is more suitable for UX ?

Comment: @KisHanSarsecHaGajjar Why do you think it should be on UX? Note that questions about tools primarily used for programming are on topic on SO. Also, he is *not* asking why (from a UX point of view) VisualStudio is using different colors to display similar words, but why (from a syntactical/programming) point of view those words are considered different (and hence highlighted differently). In fact the whole question could be rephrased removing all references to colors, UI and VisualStudio and reduced to "Is there a semantic difference between `true` and `TRUE`?". So: definitely on topic on SO.

Comment: @Bakuriu I was confused (that is why I mentioned as "query"), thnx for detailed explanation :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`true` and `false` are *keywords* in C++ so your IDE (not the compiler) is painting them blue.

TRUE and FALSE are often defined by various headers, primarily for compatibility with C and older C++ compilers where `true` and `false` are **not** keywords.

As for their equivalence, the C++ standard does **not** define `sizeof(true)` and `sizeof(false)` to be 1 but they **will** be the same as `sizeof(bool)`. Footnote 69 for C++ standard:

> sizeof(bool) is not required to be 1.

You'll probably find that `sizeof(TRUE)` and `sizeof(FALSE)` are `sizeof(int)` since TRUE and FALSE are often defined as `int` types, but it would be unwise to assume this.

Answer (score 38):

`false` is a keyword in C++; it's blue for the same reason `for` is blue. `FALSE` is a preprocessor macro declared by the Windows API; it's purple for the same reason `MYFILE_H_DEFINED` is purple. If you go into the editor preferences for C++, you'll see the colors MSVC is using for different identifiers.

Incidentally, TRUE and FALSE are WinAPI-specific and are a throwback to C, and should not be used except when communicating with the WinAPI.

Answer (score 5):

The syntax highlighting is just for the user so you can understand that the word you typed in is a `keyword` for the language. Every language has their own set of keywords.

Just to clarify, that is not the 'compiler' changing the color. That is visual studio doing that for you. Based on the the extension of the file. I.e (.cpp .java .py .js) the software will change for different words.

The capital TRUE and FALSE are specific to Windows API (more specifically--macros), and as for the lower case, it is specific to c++ language.